Implement a compile time polynomial expression
I am trying to implement the a0 + a1 * x ^ 1 + ... + an * x ^ n expression at compile time, where a0 ... an are coefficients stored in an array like container.
I came up with the following, but I am not sure it is really doing what I want it to:
#include <array>
#include <cmath>
#include <utility>

template <size_t Order>
struct poly_transform {
    template <typename CoeffsT>
    double operator()(CoeffsT&& coeffs, const double& x)
    {
        return pow(x, Order) * coeffs[Order] 
            + poly_transform<Order- 1>{}(std::forward<CoeffsT>(coeffs), x);
    }
};

template <>
struct poly_transform<0> {
    template <typename CoeffsT>
    double operator()(CoeffsT&& coeffs, const double& x)
    {
        return coeffs[0];
    }
};

e.g.
//                            a0 a1 a2
std::array<double, 3> coeffs {1, 2, 3};
double prediction = poly_transform<2>{}(coeffs, 2.3);

Question: will this really translate into the desired compile time expression?

Not sure about the question about compile time, but code works.

The Horner's method.

Yes it works. The question is whether the call in the last line is compiled as the polynomial expression I want or via recursive runtime calls.

What do you want to build at compile time exactly? (result, formula, ...)

You might add constexpr at several places to have computation at compile time.

In this particular example coeffs[0] + coeffs[1] * 2.3 + coeffs[2] * 2.3 ^ 2

It is indeed coeffs[0] + coeffs[1] * x + coeffs[2] * x², but it is computed at runtime.

Ok, that is all fine. But will there be any actual functor call at runtime? That's what I want to avoid.

pow is not constexpr until C++26

Yes (unless optimizer, with as-if rule, remove it).

constexpr demo (with no recursive way).

This is very simple

To check if it actually works at compile time, use consteval to force compile time execution. Once that compiles, you know it's possible to execute at compile time. Then you can switch back to constexpr to allow runtime stuff.

That is exactly the reason why I developed aerobus
In this library, given your coefficients are 64 bits integers, you case would translate to
using P = aerobus::make_int_polynomial_t<aerobus::i64, an, ..., a1, a0>;
double my_eval(const double& x) {
    return P::eval(x); // this is constexpr
}

where P::eval function unrolls the Horner algorithm at compile time.
Your coefficients can also be "rational" numbers (a pair p/q with p and q integers), for example to approximate real coefficients.
See doc or code examples for more details.

First of all, you cannot use double/float as a non-type template parameter.
Check here for more details on this.
On the other hand, if you prefer to use integer as X then I think the following may work for you:
#include <array>
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdlib>

template <std::size_t X, std::size_t Order>
struct CalculatePow
{
    constexpr static inline std::size_t kResult = X * CalculatePow<X, Order - 1>::kResult;
};

template <std::size_t X>
struct CalculatePow<X, 1>
{
    constexpr static inline std::size_t kResult = X;
};

template <std::size_t X>
struct CalculatePow<X, 0>
{
    constexpr static inline std::size_t kResult = 1;
};

template <std::size_t X, size_t Order>
struct poly_transform
{
    constexpr poly_transform() = default;

    template <typename ArrayT>
    static constexpr double calculate(ArrayT&& coeffs)
    {
        return (CalculatePow<X, Order>::kResult * coeffs[Order]) + poly_transform<X, Order - 1>::calculate(coeffs);
    }
};

template <std::size_t X>
struct poly_transform<X, 0>
{
    constexpr poly_transform() = default;

    template <typename ArrayT>
    static constexpr double calculate(ArrayT&& coeffs)
    {
        return CalculatePow<X, 0>::kResult * coeffs[0];
    }
};

int main()
{
    {
        constexpr double result = CalculatePow<0, 5>::kResult;
        static_assert(result == 0, "");
    }

    {
        constexpr double result = CalculatePow<1, 5>::kResult;
        static_assert(result == 1, "");
    }

    {
        constexpr double result = CalculatePow<2, 5>::kResult;
        static_assert(result == 32, "");
    }

    {
        constexpr double result = CalculatePow<5, 5>::kResult;
        static_assert(result == 3125, "");
    }

    {
        constexpr double result = CalculatePow<1, 900>::kResult;
        static_assert(result == 1, "");
    }

    constexpr std::array<double, 3> coeffs{1, 2, 3};
    constexpr double prediction = poly_transform<2, 1>::calculate(coeffs);
    static_assert(prediction == 5);

    return 0;
}


Is this AI generated? There is no reason for the first sentence which is very compelling.
